# How to unstub a method using Kiwi

Tags: ios, kiwi

I have a macro for test purposes that creates a navigation controller, sets it as the root view controller of the main window and put the view controller being tested inside the navigation controller.

I also would like to for every invocation of `pushViewController:animated:` to change the animated parameter to `NO`.

How can I achieve that?

I tried using `stub:withBlock:` and then calling the `pushViewController:animated:` inside the block with the view controller being pushed (params[0]) and NO but this leads to an infinite loop.

There is also the `stub:withArguments:` but in that case I don't have the reference to the view controller being pushed since it's a macro used in several places.

The only way I could think about it is to use the `stub:withBlock:` and inside the block remove the stub and normally call `pushViewController:params[0]:NO` but I couldn't find a way to remove a stub.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Kiwi's stubbing functionality isn't really designed to do that.

There are two main things it's for:

- Isolating the code under test from the rest of the system (by replacing a method implementation with a fake one)
- Making assertions about the API contract between objects in the system

If you want to globally change the default behaviour of a method, I think what you're after is a more general-purpose method-swizzling solution. Kiwi's stubbing functionality may be implemented in part with swizzling, but it's a much more focused tool.